# SQL Server RANK() Function to get Overall Ranking

Tags: sql-server

I wish to get the overall ranking of a runner's race time by a particular event.

```
SELECT a.EventName, b.RunEventName, c.RaceTime, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY RaceTime)Rank
FROM dbo.Event AS a, dbo.RunEvent as b, dbo.RegistrationEvent as c, dbo.Registration as d
WHERE b.EventId = a.EventId
AND c.RunEventId = b.RunEventId
AND c.RegistrationId = d.RegistrationId
AND b.RunEventId = '1'
AND NOT RaceTime IS NULL AND NOT RaceTime = 0
```

My query results are as shown below:

```
    EventName               RunEventName     RaceTime   Rank
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   Event 1                 Run              1049       1
2   Event 1                 Run              1179       2
3   Event 1                 Run              1407       3
4   Event 1                 Run              1648       4
5   Event 1                 Run              1817       5
6   Event 1                 Run              1865       6
```

If I do an SQL statement to only display row number 5, my results are:

```
    EventName         RunEventName          RaceTime    Rank
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   Event1            Run                   1817        1
```

The expected output for rank should be 5 but it shows 1 instead.

Comment: well, of course, that's how `RANK` works, it ranks a set of rows, so if your query returns only one row, it will rank it according to the rest (and since there are none, it returns 1)

Comment: @Lamak so there is no way I can grab the rank (in this case, 5) from the selected row?

Comment: you can use your query as a derived table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your current query as a CTE, and then select the row you want from the CTE.

```
WITH cte AS ({your current query})
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE Rank=5
```

Comment: Much thanks. It works. Just a side question, I'm trying to get this SQL statement to work on a TableAdapter from my DataSet in VB.net Winforms, it says that **The OVER SQL construct is not supported.** I believe the OVER comes from my RANK() function. Why do I get this error?

Comment: What version is your SQL Server?  Have you checked if your version support RANK()?

Comment: I recommend that you post this as a new question, you would need to show all the vb.net code you are using to construct the table adapter.